# Merging two pandas dataframes based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes, but only where specific column values
contain or do not contain certain values.
I am trying the following code,  but is does not result in the required output

```
def function()  
   new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['col4', 'col5', 'col6'])
   return new_df

new_df = np.where(df1['col1 '] == '1' & df1['col2']== 'stock') & 
df[~df['col3'].str.contains('stock', na=False)],new_df.apply(function), new_df)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframes and your expected output please? We can't help when you say "it does not result in the required output" if we can't see what that is.

Comment: You should first filter, then merge. Like: 
`new_df = df1[(df1['col1 '] == '1') & (df1['col2']== 'stock')).merge(df[~df['col3'].str.contains('stock', na=False)])`